# How to get list of all subscribed channels of user using youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api, laravel-5.4, google-apis-explorer

I am using Laravel-php, I have following code :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId(env('GOOGLE_ID'));
        $client->setClientSecret(env('GOOGLE_SECRET'));
        //$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");

        $youtube = new \Google_Service_YouTube($client);

        $searchResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('snippet', array('mine' => true));

        //$subscriptions = Curl::to('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions')->withData(['part' => 'snippet', 'mine' => 'true'])->get();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($searchResponse);
```

Above code gives me following error :

```
Google_Service_Exception in REST.php line 118:
{  
"error": {
  "errors": [
  {
     "domain": "usageLimits",
     "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
     "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.      Continued use requires signup.",
     "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
 }],
 "code": 403,
 "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."


 }
}
```

I have tried to use CURL call also but that also gives me same error, any suggestions will save my day
What am I missing in code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your error means that you haven't set up a Google APIs console project. The resource you are accessing requires OAuth authorization. You need to [obtain authorization credentials in the Google Developers Console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) to be able to use OAuth 2.0 authorization.

1. Open the [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_).
2. The API supports API keys and OAuth 2.0 credentials. In your case, use OAuth 2.0 for your project:

   - **OAuth 2.0:** Your application must send an OAuth 2.0 token with any request that accesses private user data. Your application sends a client ID and, possibly, a client secret to obtain a token. You can generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts, or installed applications.

     See the [Creating OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_OAuth2_Tokens) section for more information.

You may also check this related thread: [list user subscriptions to all youtube channels after getting access token](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?306613-list-user-subscriptions-to-all-youtube-channels-after-getting-access-token)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that it needs to be an authenticated call.
So you need to get the person to "Authenticate" through the Oauth2 and collect the token.

Then with the token send this call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=id,snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=50&channelId='.$channelId.'&access_token='.$access_token
```

Then you can access the JSON response and collect them.